# How to stop postgres cron jobs ? is there even a way to stop it?

Tags: postgresql

Suppose if I run the following cron job in my DB:

```
SELECT cron.schedule('30 3 * * 6', $$DELETE FROM events WHERE event_time < now() - interval '1 week'$$);
```

will that ever stop running ? How can I delete it if I do not want the job to run anymore ?

If there is no other way I can stop the above job, Please suggest an alternative that I can use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is not a native PostgreSQL-function, how did you install this function?

Comment: I did not install it yet, but I was looking for something that recurring every day and I found this. But looking at that seemed like it wouldn't stop. So just wanted to confirm.  Please refer: [link] (http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/43937/how-to-run-recurring-tasks-on-a-postgresql-database-without-a-cron-like-tool)

Comment: `pg_cron` is a third-party extension, not part of Postgres itself. You will find your answer in their [README](https://github.com/citusdata/pg_cron/blob/master/README.md).

Comment: @NickBarnes yes, okay. But, that does not answer my original question.

Comment: Search the readme for "Stop scheduling a job"

Comment: @NickBarnes :p thank you!

Answer (score 20):

You can find the job ID in the cron.job table and use the `cron.unschedule` function to stop the job:

```
postgres=# SELECT * FROM cron.job;
 jobid │  schedule  │                             command                             │ nodename  │ nodeport │ database │ username │ active │ jobname 
───────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┼───────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────
     1 │ 30 3 * * 6 │ DELETE FROM events WHERE event_time < now() - interval '1 week' │ localhost │     5432 │ postgres │ marco    │ t      │ 
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT cron.unschedule(1);
 unschedule 
────────────
 t
(1 row)

postgres=# SELECT * FROM cron.job;
 jobid │ schedule │ command │ nodename │ nodeport │ database │ username │ active │ jobname 
───────┼──────────┼─────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼──────────┼────────┼─────────
(0 rows)
```

Answer (score 0):

To temporarily disable a cron job without unscheduling it, use the `active` column.

```sql
BEGIN;

UPDATE cron.job 
SET active = false 
WHERE jobid = 1
  AND active
RETURNING *;

COMMIT; -- verify first
```

Supported as of pg_cron v1.1.0 (March 22, 2018).